# Weird compile error when assigning pointers in increment part of C++ for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

I want to write a function in C++ about finding the intersection node of 2 linked lists.

The definition of linkedlist is trival as belows:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

My idea is loop over the 2 lists and find the last different node.

All the variables are `ListNode` pointers.

The problem happens when I tried to put `pa = headA` and `pb = headB` up into the increment part of for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < min_len; i++, pa = headA, pb = headB) {

    while (pa->next != last_same_node) pa = pa->next;
    while (pb->next != last_same_node) pb = pb->next;

    if (pa != pb) break;
    else last_same_node = pa;
}
```

It worked well when I put them down like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < min_len; i++) {

    pa = headA;
    pb = headB;

    while (pa->next != last_same_node) pa = pa->next;
    while (pb->next != last_same_node) pb = pb->next;

    if (pa != pb) break;
    else last_same_node = pa;
}
```

The error message VC gave me is this:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00BD34B7 in leetcode.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

I thought the assignments didn't happen so that the pointer reached an invalid memory. I've got no idea what cause this.

Comment: That´s not a compiler error...

Comment: This is an exception raised by your application because you tried to read unexistent memory location. Check your memory usage by simple code reading, debugger or valgrind.

Comment: That's a run-time *crash*. Run a debug-build in a debugger, and the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. The debugger will then let you examine the function call stack, and let you walk up the call stack until you reach your code (if you're not there already) where you can examine values of variables.

Comment: As for the reasons for the crash, what if `pa` or `pb` becomes `NULL`?

Comment: Thank you @deviantfan, I made a mistake and it's definitely a run time error.

Comment: Thank you @Victor Polevoy, I made a mistake and it's definitely a run time error

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I follow your advice and finally found my miss. Thank you

Comment: ***0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.*** This should tell you that you are most likely dereferencing a null pointer. And trying to read some value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version only executes the lines between loop iterations. The second version executes them on every loop iteration. The difference is that the second version executes them on the first iteration, while the first version doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, it's intuitive and helped me understand this issue.